# Getting a button to switch cards

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, cardlayout

I have a log in GUI that when i click a button, it gets text from the username and password, and if it is correct, it moves on to a new panel. i have the panel called `optionPanel` and i want the button to go to it specifically. all of the panels are set up as cards, so i can switch between them smoothly. I know how to make the button move to the next panel/card in the sequence, but i don't know how to make it go to the panel/card called `optionPanel`.

EDIT:
I dont know if im being very clear, but in my head, this makes perfect sense. please tell me how i can be more clear so i can get an answer.
THANKS

Comment: What do you mean? You can select one by name, not just the next one. What's missing?

Comment: So what's stopping you from calling CardLayout#show(...)?  You're question isn't near complete enough, and so you're forcing us to guess. Don't do that.

Comment: sorry. im kind of new to java, and i get the basics. see the edit and post more q's

Comment: @ajv857: I've seen your edit but again it doesn't come close to giving us enough information to say exactly what your problem is or how to solve it. It again suggests that the problem has roots more in a misunderstanding of core Java basics (and not likely a Swing-specific issue), perhaps by not having a variable in the scope necessary to call its methods. Without more useful information again all we can do is guess. Please have a look at this link for helpful suggestions: [How To Ask Smart Questions](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Comment: You state: `" all i know is how to set them up in the gui interface for netbeans"`. And this may be a cause for your code problems: by letting NetBeans create your Swing GUI code, you shield yourself from learning and understanding Swing. Until you better understand Java and Swing, don't do this as you're setting yourself up for problems such as what you're experiencing now. Until you know Swing well, I suggest that you go to the Swing tutorials and learn to code it by hand. The understanding gained will not be wasted, trust me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: ok. that makes good sense. thank you for that. do you know of any good online tutorials?

Comment: @ajv857: yes -- and you already posted a link to it in your pre-edited original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
// Create the panels
JPanel loginPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel someOtherPanel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel someOtherPanel2 = new JPanel();
JPanel optionPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel someOtherPanel3 = new JPanel();

// Add them to a card layout
JPanel cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
cards.add(loginPanel, "loginPanel");
cards.add(someOtherPanel1, "someOtherPanel1");
cards.add(someOtherPanel2, "someOtherPanel2");
cards.add(optionPanel, "optionPanel");
cards.add(someOtherPanel3, "someOtherPanel3");

...

// Switch to the optionPanel
cards.getLayout().show(cards, "optionPanel");
```

Comment: well, that works kinda, but the `cards.getLayout` and (`cards` are highlighted as wrong, and i cant tell why.

Comment: @ajv857: if you show your code, perhaps we can tell you why. It sounds like you're not tripping up on Swing, but rather on basic core Java issues such as variable scope.

Answer (score 0):

don't you just need

```
cardLayout.show(cards, "optionPanel");
```

or am i missing something completely non-obvious?